# Will my Kindle Fire still work the same with GO Launcher?

Tags: launcher, amazon-kindle-fire, go-launcher-ex

I was thinking of getting GO Launcher on my Kindle Fire, since I want a new look on my Fire. But, I don't want to change it's defaults programs and functionality.

If I get GO Launcher, will I still be able to open my Docs and Books in normal Kindle Fire fashion? Will it change the functionality of my Fire?

Answer (score 2):

The only way I've found is from the ugly old Carousel.  I keep a link to it accessible on my new launcher and go there to open a book or document.  It's not as graceful as, say, a direct link to the book, but it works.

Comment: When you open the book, is it still normal Kindle Fire layout?

Comment: Yes, it looks exactly as it did/would have without the 3rd-party launcher.  Indeed, at that point, the 3rd-party launcher isn't in use.